# How to benchmark HBase on my own table？

Tags: java, python, hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I have a big table in HBase and it has a lot of data. I want to benchmark HBase on my own table. In a word，I want to test the time and throughput when 600 threads（600 clients） visits this table. But tools like YCSB should create a table first and test this table, not my own table. So is there any method to test my own table?(I'm Chinese and my English is not good!Sorry!)